# Android: Drawing rectangular imageViews over existing image

Tags: java, android

I am making an Android app and attempting to programatically draw some clickable, rectangular blocks with text on one of two custom views contained in a ScrollLayout. The XML for my ScrollLayout looks like this:

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/calendarGridContainerView"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/employeeSpinnerContainer"
            android:paddingBottom="72dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:elevation="1dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:id="@+id/schedule_view_container"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/schedule_time_frame"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5">

                    <include
                        layout="@layout/schedule_time_view"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="100dp" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/schedule_grid_frame"
                    android:minHeight="179dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/schedule_time_frame"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                    android:layout_weight="8">

                    <include
                        layout="@layout/schedule_grid_layout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />
                </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Note that the layout called `scheduleGridLayout` is where I am trying to draw these rectangles. It has the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<(package).ScheduleGridLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:scheduleGridLayout="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

</(package).ScheduleGridLayout>
```

(When copying the above code, I removed the package name.)

In the constructor for `ScheduleGridLayout.java`, I call `this.setWillNotDraw(false);`.  Before drawing the rectangles, I draw some horizontal gridlines on ScheduleGridLayout through its overridden `onDraw()` method:

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    final int width = getWidth();
    final int rowHeight = ScheduleTimeLayout.SCHEDULE_VIEW_ROW_HEIGHT + ScheduleTimeLayout.TIME_LABEL_HEIGHT;
    for(int i = 0; i < ScheduleTimeLayout.TIME_SEGMENT_COUNT + 1; i++){
        if ((i % (int)(1.0/ScheduleTimeLayout.SEGMENT_SIZE)) == 0){
            paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            paint.setStrokeWidth((float)4.0);
        }
        else{
            paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            paint.setStrokeWidth((float)2.0);
        }
        int y = 178 + (int)(i*(rowHeight + 1) - rowHeight/2.0);
        canvas.drawLine(0, y, width, y, paint);
    }
```

Since I want the rectangles to be clickable, I have to add them as some sort of views rather than simply drawing their images onto the canvas. I've tried a few different ways to draw the rectangles-- currently I try to do it in `onFinishInflate()` in `ScheduleGridLayout.java`, like so:

```
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(60,200,Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
    tempCanvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0,0,600,600), 2, 2, paint);
    ImageView testBlock = new ImageView(getContext());
    testBlock.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), tempBitmap));
    addView(testBlock);
```

However, there the block does not appear when I do this.

In a separate attempt, I tried creating an XML layout file for the schedule block:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content">
<com.dalc.dalccalendar.ScheduleBlock
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:scheduleGridLayout="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/schedule_block">
</com.dalc.dalccalendar.ScheduleBlock>
```

In `ScheduleBlock.java`, I override `onMeasure()` to set the size of the block using `setMeasuredDimension`, and I override `onDraw()` with the following code:

```
super.onDraw(canvas);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    String bgColor = "#FF0000"; 
    setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(bgColor));
```

I noticed that red rectangle does appear in the XML file's preview, but not when I try to add the block in `ScheduleGridLayout`:

```
 FrameLayout blockFrame = (FrameLayout)LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.schedule_block_container, this, false);
 testBlock.setElevation(4);
 addView(blockFrame);
```

Not only does the rectangle not appear when I run the app, but I've found that the `onDraw()` method for ScheduleBlock is not called. What am I doing wrong? How can I make these blocks appear inside my scrollview on top of the gridlines and be interactable with clicks? I'd prefer to be able to do with with custom views if possible, since each block needs to be associated with specific data.

Comment: "Since I want the rectangles to be clickable, I have to add them as some sort of views" - Not really. You can override the `onTouchEvent()` method, and check if an event happens within your rectangles' bounds. Should be a little simpler than trying to juggle a bunch of child `View`s.

Comment: I'm in the process of implementing it this way, though I'd still like to know how to do it with custom views if possible since all the rectangles will have similar behavior anyway.